# Why is my condition always met?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I created my var outside the function, then in the function I add++ only when cards are flipped. my console writes cardserial=0, but still the "return" works and the rest of my function doesn't work at all. 
why does the **if (cardserial == 2 );** return true?

```
var cardserial = 0;

// This function is called whenever the user click a card
function cardClicked(elCard) {
console.log(cardserial)

if (cardserial == 2 ); {
console.log('prevent triple card flip')
return; 
} 

if (typeof startTime === 'undefined') {
...
 var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');
    cardserial++;
    console.log('Second')
...
```

Comment: You did not post enough of your code.

Comment: The if statements syntax is `if(condition) statement` now `{}` is a block statement (a statement conposed of multiple statements), so if you do `if(sth); {}` you seperate the block from the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Because you added a semi-colon after the if statement `if (cardserial == 2 ); {`
That runs the block of code after it.

It should be `if (cardserial == 2) {`.

Comment: @AnneWithAnE I don't want to bug you too much, but I noticed that you are new here. Usually when someone answers your question and the answer solves your problem, you tick it as correct. It helps the community know that the answer given was the right solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a Semicolon terminating `if` . JavaScript thinks that you have an empty statement there, and everything to the right of it is treated as no longer belonging. And next line is considered as an separate block. It should have been

```
if (cardserial == 2 ) {
  console.log('prevent triple card flip')
 return; 
}
```